# SjLj undefined while trying to develop a Qt application using Netbeans

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

Good afternoon all,

I'm trying to develop my first Qt application. I'm getting many errors like the following if I try to link in static libraries with my own code:

```
H:/NetBeansProjects/CommonLib/aes.cpp:607: undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
H:/NetBeansProjects/CommonLib/aes.cpp:607: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
H:/NetBeansProjects/CommonLib/aes.cpp:615: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
```

My code compiles and works when not used with Qt.
The Qt program compiled and worked before I tried to link my libraries.
Google-ing it shows it may be a mismatch between compilers used to build the two sets of code. I set the Netbeans environment to use the same tool chain to build both with no
change.

I'm using Windows, NetBeans 6.9.1, and the latest Qt. I've set the compiler to use
the Qt supplied mingw compiler.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like no code will link with the new Qt/mingw. My non Qt unit tests now do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

It was linking in libraries from previous versions of my projects.

I installed a new version of Mingw compiler with Qt to fix an issue. I set up the new compiler as a toolchain with a different name in Netbeans.

I did a clean and build on the referenced projects using the new tool chain. Netbeans stored the compiled library in a directory named from the tool chain. It left the old version of the library in another directory named for the original tool chain.

When you add a project reference to a library Netbeans imports the path to the library. If you change the tool chain (and therefore change the path to the library) other projects still point to the old code. You have to remove the project references and re-add them.